# SQLite searching for user in table

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

```
 // This returns a count of 1, so the table does exist, and I know the user exists becaue I have just added him in...
Int32 tableCount = database.Query(map, "SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = 'UserTable'", ps).Count;

//but when I try this the count is 0....what am I doing wrong?
 Int32 tableCount2 = database.Query(map, "SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = 'UserTable' AND NameOfUser = '" + personsName + "'", ps).Count;

t
```

rying to see if the user exists...what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SQL Injections**

First, I want to say that this code is vulnerable to SQL Injections, .

**Why does the query not work?**

Because 'NameOfUser' is not a column of sqlite_master, but it is a column of UserTable, I suppose.

sqlite_master consists of the following columns:

```
type
name
tbl_name
rootpage
sql
```

**How can I make it work?**

```
Int32 tableCount2 = database.Query(map, "SELECT * FROM UserTable WHERE NameOfUser = '" + personsName + "'", ps).Count;
```

But, as said before, you better use C# SQLite prepared statements to prevent SQL injection, check this: [C# SQLite tutorial](http://zetcode.com/csharp/sqlite/) and search for 'prepared'

Please mark as answer when it worked.

CU

Comment: yes so for a fix is to add 'NameOfUser' into sqlite_master class?

Comment: thank you for your help that worked and I will loo into the tutorial thanks again